# why can I still docker pull after docker logout

Tags: docker, docker-registry

context(what I do while using docker):

- docker login URL
  [auth info in config.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHF5Y.png)
- docker pull/push ops
- docker logout URL
  [auth info removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXNUQ.png)

my question is, why does docker pull/push cmd still work after docker logout?
I tested on my own Ubuntu.

Comment: You probably log into a private repository, right?

Comment: yeap, I built a docker harbor service as my private registry, so the behavior on private repository is different from public repository?

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the answer!

it relates with the access level in harbor.

if the repository's access level is public, you can do 'docker pull image', could not do 'docker push image'

if the repository's access level is private, neither 'docker pull image' nor 'docker push image'

Comment: Your question indicated you can still push to this repo.